# Retrofit2 complex request

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to create a request using Retrofit2. I created the request using a standard library:

```
path = "https://www.iii.com/?id="+id+"&data=";
query = "{\"name\":\""+name+"\",\"quantity\":20}";
```

Final link is:

```
link = path+URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
```

I tried different Retrofit2 options, but I can't understand how to translate my link to Retrofit2 link using together path and query with url encoded?

Comment: use retrofit api for this instead of building the url manually

Comment: This is what I want to do, but I do not understand how to create URL

Comment: retrofit creates it for you, read the docs

Comment: Why don't you use POST because you are passing a request json body?

Comment: Tim, Now I am working with Retrofit, but I faced with complex url and the question about the url. How to build using @GET annotations.

Comment: Tenten this is GET method

Comment: I've added an answer how to parse retrofit get query parameters, I assume that you know how to call it. If not, please provide your code on how you are calling your retrofit requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse GET query parameters to retrofit using this code:

```
@GET("https://www.iii.com")
Observable<ResponseBody> getSomething(
        @Query("id") int id,
        @Query("data") String data
);
```

Retrofit will build it for you. Just pass your variables (assuming you know how to call retrofit requests) and retrofit will url encode it for you. You can refer to this link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

> Values are converted to strings using Retrofit.stringConverter(Type, Annotation[]) (or Object.toString(), if no matching string converter is installed) **and then URL encoded**. null values are ignored. Passing a List or array will result in a query parameter for each non-null item.

Comment: Tenten,thank you, where is URLEncoder for the "data" part?

Comment: Just add another @Query for 'data'

Comment: Yes, but i need sometging like this: {"name":"bob","quantity":6}  in url encoded. It isn't a simple Query.

Comment: What are you trying to do? From what I understand to your question, you just want to translate your manually build link to retrofit link, just pass your String query = " {\"name\":\"bob\",\"quantity\":6} " to the getSomething(id, query); Retrofit will url encode it.

Comment: Tenten, you correctly understood my question. I was surprised that it is necessary to transfer the whole string {\"name\":\"bob\",\"quantity\":6} and it can't be processed using Retrofit2 parameters.

Comment: GET request on retrofit doesn't handle JSON, you must use POST to pass object and retrofit will turn it to JSON. GET request just handle the url encode for you, but you still need to pass the json string.

Answer (score 1):

you can add anotation for that like below

```
@Headers("charset=UTF-8")
@GET("https://www.iii.com")
Observable<ResponseBody> getSomething(
        @Query("id") int id,
        @Query("data") String data
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your variant.